# MVC3: One controller, multiple routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a MVC3 application with multiple areas. Every area is a different application module, but they share one common functionality - Reporting. So, I wrote a reporting controller and views in root area and wanted to attach them to all the areas using routing. This method worked well with MVC1, but I then upgraded to MVC3, the routes stopped working and always return 404.

Routing structure is similar for every module/area:

```
Module1/Reports.aspx/
Module1/PreportView.aspx/{id}
Module1/{controller}/{action}
Module1/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

and the route registration for module is made by the following method:

```
protected override void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context, string arearoot, string defaultControllerName){
  context.MapRoute(arearoot + "Reports", arearoot + "/Reports.aspx",
    new { action = "Index", controller = "Reports" }, new string[] { "Controllers" }); //this should work in MVC3 according to docs

  context.MapRoute(arearoot + "ReportView", arearoot + "/ReportView.aspx/{id}",
    new { action = "Show", controller = "Controllers.ReportsController" });//this method worked in MVC1

  context.MapRoute(arearoot,
    arearoot + "/{controller}.aspx/{action}",
    new { controller = defaultControllerName, action = "Index" },
    GetRouteNamespaces());

  context.MapRoute(arearoot + "ItemSpecific",
    arearoot + "/{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}");
}

protected string[] GetRouteNamespaces() {
  return new string[] { "Controllers.Module1" }; //returns proper namespace for each module
}
```

I have tried to attach **RouteDebugger** (which fails because of .aspx extensions), and **Glimpse**, but none of them show me any problems, the routing table seemed to be OK, but when I try to navigate to reports, I always get the 404 error code.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you call the actions (in your aspx/c-Files)?

Answer (score 0):

- Please check area registration routes inside your area directory.

  - Also get all list of registered route during debugging. Route get registered at many in ASP.net MVC 2 or later if you are using
    Area.

    - You also have to specify area during registration of route. ( Same way as you specified Controller)